Principal connection form uniquely determined by pullback along local sections
I will follow Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics, Part II. I am trying to prove corollary 1.3.12, but I will state all relevant information here as well. Let $\pi: P \to M$ be a smooth principal $G$-bundle and $U_i \subset M$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ be open subsets on which local sections $s_i \in \Gamma_{U_i}(P)$ of P exists. Let $\kappa_i: P \to G$ denote the unique smooth maps such that $p = s_i\circ \pi(p) \cdot \kappa_i(p)$.
Given $\mathfrak{g}$-valued differential forms $\mathcal{A}_i$ on $U_i$ such that
$$(\mathcal{A}_1)_{m} = Ad_{\rho_{21}(m)^{-1}}(\mathcal{A}_2)_{m} + (\rho_{21}^\ast\theta)_m,$$
where $\theta$ is the Maurer-Cartan form and $\rho_{21}(m):= \kappa_2(p) \cdot \kappa_1(p)^{-1}$ for $p\in \pi^{-1}(m)$, is the following form on $\pi^{-1}(U_1\cap U_2)$ independent of the choice between $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$?
$$A_p := Ad_{\kappa_i(p)^{-1}}(\pi^\ast\mathcal{A}_i)_p + (\kappa_i^\ast\theta)_p$$
While it is easy to see how the first summand is obtained from the corresponding other local representation, I don't see how we obtain the correct second summand.
Thank you very much in advance!

The first part of Corollary 1.3.12 in the book requires proving the transformation law of local representatives of a given connection 1-form $\omega$ on $P$. For this, use the formula you mentioned (from Proposition 1.3.11) and write $\omega=\mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_i^{-1})\pi^*\mathcal{A}_i+\kappa_i^*\theta$ in terms of $\mathcal{A}_i$. The result is obtained by applying $s_j^*$ to this expression and using that $\kappa_i\circ s_j=\rho_{ij}$.
The second part is to show that a system of $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-forms $\{\mathcal{A}_i\}$ on $M$ satisfying the transformation law defines a connection on $P$. If we appeal to the proposition, this is essentially the same computation: say over $U_i$, we define $\omega$ in terms of $\mathcal{A}_i$. It is easy to verify that it is a connection form, so Proposition 1.3.11 can be used to express $\omega$ in terms of its local representative $s_j^*\omega$ on $U_i\cap U_j$, but by the transformation law, this is just $\mathcal{A}_j$. So the two expressions are equivalent.

I believe you were trying to substitute the transformation law into one expression to see that it gives the other. This approach can also be taken and does not require appealing to the proposition (but the ideas are essentially the same): using $\rho_{ij}\circ\pi=\kappa_i\cdot\kappa_j$, we have
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_j^{-1})\pi^*\mathcal{A}_j+\kappa_j^*\theta &=\mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_j^{-1})\big(\mathrm{Ad}(\rho_{ij}\circ\pi)^{-1}\pi^*\mathcal{A}_i+(\rho_{ij}\circ\pi)^*\theta\big)+\kappa_j^*\theta\\
    &=\mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_i^{-1})\pi^*\mathcal{A}_i+\mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_j^{-1})(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})^*\theta+\kappa_j^*\theta.
\end{align}
To simplify the middle term, let $p\in P_{U_i\cap U_j}$ and apply the right-equivariance and left-invariance of the Maurer-Cartan form:
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_j^{-1}(p))(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})^*\theta|_p&=\mathrm{Ad}(\kappa_j^{-1}(p))\theta_{\kappa_i(p)\kappa_j^{-1}(p)}\circ d(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})_p\\
    &=R_{\kappa_j(p)}^*\theta|_{\kappa_i(p)\kappa_j^{-1}(p)}\circ d(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})_p\\
    &=\theta_{\kappa_i(p)}\circ dR_{\kappa_j(p)}\circ d(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})_p\\
    &=\theta_{\kappa_i(p)}\circ\Big(d(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1}\kappa_j)_p-dL_{\kappa_i(p)\kappa_j^{-1}(p)}\circ d(\kappa_j)_p\Big)\\
    &=\kappa_i^*\theta|_p-L_{\kappa_i(p)\kappa_j^{-1}(p)}^*\theta|_{\kappa_j(p)}\circ d(\kappa_j)_p\\
    &=\kappa_i^*\theta|_p-\kappa_j^*\theta|_p.
\end{align}
(Here, we also used an identity for the differential of $\kappa_i=(\kappa_i\kappa_j^{-1})\cdot\kappa_j:P\to G$, which can be verified by taking any $v\in T_pP$ and representing it as a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $P$, as in the proof of Proposition 1.3.11 of your reference.) Substituting the above to the earlier equation shows that the 1-form on $P$ is well-defined. Verifying that it is indeed a connection form is straightforward.
